# How to swipe imageview using button right and left

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have some imagesview and I want to swipe right and left using button right and left. For Example: if i click button Right : then Picture 1 swipe to Picture 2, if i click button Left : then Picture 2 swipe to Picture 1.

Example : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q_qw-BYyNNw_9xK3XGe13mWBQV1FQW1t/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Use ViewPager or viewpager2 for this functionality. You make this my fragments with viewpager.

Comment: Okey thanks. i Will try it.